# Matching with multiple results perl

Tags: perl, while-loop, string-matching

I have a quick question.  Say I have a list of names where some are missing an "account number."  I will give an example delimited by the pipe,"|".  "_" will represent blank.

```
Jim|1

John|_

Joe|2

John|_

John|_

JEff_234

JEff_298
```

.....the list goes on for say 10,000 more rows with customers lacking ID numbers.

My goal is to populate the blanks with each appropriate ID, John for example needs an ID.

Luckily, we have a master list to reference the names to their appropriate IDs, but like I said, it would take forever to manually populate the blanks due to the large amount of rows.

The problem is that John or whomever else may have more than one ID.

The script I have will populate 'John' with only the first ID given..check the example below.

```
LINE: while (<>) {

if (/(John)/gi){print $_ = $1."|"."ID_NUMBER_5"."\n"; print STDOUT "match!!!!\n"; next};
if (/(John)/gi){print $_ = $1."|"."ID_NUMBER_6"."\n"; print STDOUT "match!!!!\n"; next};
if (/(John)/gi){print $_ = $1."|"."ID_NUMBER_7"."\n"; print STDOUT "match!!!!\n"; next};

    print;

}
```

The result I get is this:

```
Jim|1

John|ID_NUMBER_5

Joe|2

John|ID_NUMBER_5

John|ID_NUMBER_5

JEff_234

JEff_298
```

So if John has multiple "accounts" or "ids" this will not work.

My desired result is this:

```
Jim|1

John|ID_NUMBER_5

Joe|2

John|ID_NUMBER_6

John|ID_NUMBER_7

JEff_234

JEff_298
```

Any thoughts or proper methods of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the accounts in a hash of lists. Use the keys of the hash when looking for a match on each line.  Each time you find a match and still have account list entries shift out one from the corresponding list.

```
my %accountMap = ("John", ["ID_NUMBER_5", "ID_NUMBER_6", "ID_NUMBER_7"],
                  "Bob", ["ID_NUMBER_8"]);

LINE: while (<>) {
  foreach $acctName (keys %accountMap) {
    if (/($acctName)/gi && $accountMap{$acctName} && scalar @{$accountMap{$acctName}} > 0) {
      my @accounts = @{$accountMap{$acctName}};
      my $account = shift @accounts;
      $accountMap{$acctName} = [@accounts];
      print $_ = $1."|". $account ."\n";
      next LINE;
    }
  }
  print;
}
```

Comment: is there any possible way you could elaborate on that or provide an example?  This is a great hard code, but what if multiple ids need to be populated for other names?

Comment: Ok..this is great and seems to work fine.  However, what if I wanted to feed a tab delimited file consisting of 2 columns, 'Name' and 'Account_ID'(i.e. John\tID_NUMBER_5\n and so on..) in to my %accountMap instead of having my %accountMap = (....); on the script?  So then whatever my key/legend file updates to or is deleted from, my %accountMap would always be current and up to date.

Comment: You'd create an empty hash and populate it with another loop, reading lines from your key file and parsing them on the tab delimiters. Every time you find a new key add it and a new list with a single entry (the value) to the hash. Every time you encounter an existing key, get the list and push the new value onto the end.

Comment: great...much appreciated!!